# What is this icon in the notifications bar

Tags: notification-icons

Hey anyone know what this symbol means? Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This would be evident by pulling down the notification bar. In this case it would accumulate into a message such as "3 apps updated", and would list them.

Answer (score 2):

Icons show that apps were updated by Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

The icon is from Google Play Store, meaning that you have multiple apps installed. One for each icon, or you have some apps updated, in which case there's an extra icon.

Pull down the notification center and you'll see all the related activities, which should read "xxx installed", or "# apps updated", along with their names.

[image]